# How much resistance is dragon shield worth?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

There is an epic destiny called "Dragonheart" in Martial Powers 2. The utility power for this epic destiny is called "Dragon Shield". The power is defined as follows:

> Daily ✦ Martial, Stance
>   Immediate Reaction ✦ Personal
>   **Trigger:** An attack bloodies you
>   **Effect:** Until the stance ends, you gain resistance to all damage equal to your Constitution modifier, and whenever you take damage from a melee attack, your resistance increases by 5 (up to a maximum of 20).  The stance ends when you are knocked unconscious or are no longer bloodied.

What is the maximum resistance you can achieve with this power?  If I have a constitution modifier of 6, will my maximum resistance with Dragon Shield, provided I keep getting hit with melee and stay bloodied, be 26 or 20?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Up to 20.

You get your stat, 6 in your example, then when you take melee damage, you go to 11, then 16, then 20. It's capped at 20 (not 20+stat).

Comment: What if I have the Essence Mage paragon path? It increases my resistances by 4. Is it before or after the limit?

Comment: @András should be after the limit.